# Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-maps-v2

MainActivity.java

```
package com.project.locationinfofinder;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    GoogleMap googlemap;
    MarkerDataSource data;
    Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (IsGooglePlay()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googlemap = mf.getMap();
        googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
        if (provider == null) {
            onProviderDisabled(provider);
        }
        // addMarker();// marker
        googlemap
                .setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng Latlang) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        final View v = li.inflate(R.layout.alertlayout, null);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                context);
                        builder.setView(v);
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("create",
                                new OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        EditText title = (EditText) v
                                                .findViewById(R.id.ettitle);
                                        EditText snippet = (EditText) v
                                                .findViewById(R.id.etsnippet);
                                        googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                .title(title.getText()
                                                        .toString())
                                                .snippet(
                                                        snippet.getText()
                                                                .toString())
                                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                                                .position(Latlang));
                                    }
                                });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dailog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        dailog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                });
        data = new MarkerDataSource(context);
        try {
            data.open();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.i("hello", "hello");
        }
        List<MarkerObj> m = data.getMyMarkers();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
            String[] slatlan = m.get(i).getPosition().split(" ");
            LatLng lat = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(slatlan[0]),
                    Double.valueOf(slatlan[1]));
            googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(m.get(i).getTitle())
                    .snippet(m.get(i).getSnippet()).position(lat)

            );
        }
        data.addMarker(new MarkerObj("title", "snippet", "27.7000 85.3500"));
        data.close();
    }

//   private void addMarker() {// marker
//   // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
//   LatLng pos = new LatLng(27.7000, 85.3500);
//   googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
//   .title("lalitpur")
//   .snippet("middel of lalitpur")
//   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
//   .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
//   .position(pos));
//  
//   }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("GPS is disabled");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Enable GPS", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dailog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent StartGPS = new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(StartGPS);

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dailog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dailog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private boolean IsGooglePlay() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return (true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play is not available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return (false);
    }
}
```

MarkerDataSource.java

```
package com.project.locationinfofinder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MarkerDataSource {
    MarkerDb dbhelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String[] cols = {MarkerDb.TITLE, MarkerDb.SNIPPET, MarkerDb.POSITION};

    public MarkerDataSource(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        dbhelper = new MarkerDb(c);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException{
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }
    public void addMarker(MarkerObj m){
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(MarkerDb.TITLE, m.getTitle());
        v.put(MarkerDb.SNIPPET, m.getSnippet());
        v.put(MarkerDb.POSITION, m.getPosition());
        db.insert(MarkerDb.TABLE_NAME, null, v);
    }
public List<MarkerObj> getMyMarkers(){
    List<MarkerObj> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerObj>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(MarkerDb.TABLE_NAME, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        MarkerObj m = CursorToMarker(cursor);
        markers.add(m);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    cursor.close();
    return markers;


}

private MarkerObj CursorToMarker(Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MarkerObj m = new MarkerObj();
    m.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
    m.setSnippet(cursor.getString(1));
    m.setPosition(cursor.getString(2));
    return m;
}
}
```

MarkerObj.java

package com.project.locationinfofinder;

```
public class MarkerObj {
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String snippet;
    private String position;

    public MarkerObj() {

    }

    public MarkerObj(long id, String title, String snippet, String position) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.snippet = snippet;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public MarkerObj(String title, String snippet, String position) {
        this.title = title;
        this.snippet = snippet;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSnippet() {
        return snippet;
    }

    public void setSnippet(String snippet) {
        this.snippet = snippet;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

}
```

logcat

```
08-06 08:15:10.960: D/dalvikvm(8084): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
08-06 08:15:10.960: W/dalvikvm(8084): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 27
08-06 08:15:10.960: D/dalvikvm(8084): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
08-06 08:15:10.960: D/dalvikvm(8084): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
08-06 08:15:11.085: W/dalvikvm(8084): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/w; (734)
08-06 08:15:11.085: W/dalvikvm(8084): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/w;' failed
08-06 08:15:11.085: W/dalvikvm(8084): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ap/as; (6056)
08-06 08:15:11.085: W/dalvikvm(8084): Link of class 'Lmaps/ap/as;' failed
08-06 08:15:11.085: W/dalvikvm(8084): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/af/k; (5085)
08-06 08:15:11.085: W/dalvikvm(8084): Link of class 'Lmaps/af/k;' failed
08-06 08:15:11.085: E/dalvikvm(8084): Could not find class 'maps.af.k', referenced from method maps.ag.an.a
08-06 08:15:11.085: W/dalvikvm(8084): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4928 (Lmaps/af/k;) in Lmaps/ag/an;
08-06 08:15:11.085: D/dalvikvm(8084): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0091
08-06 08:15:11.109: D/dalvikvm(8084): VFY: dead code 0x0093-00a1 in Lmaps/ag/an;.a (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;Z)Lmaps/ag/an;
08-06 08:15:11.382: D/dalvikvm(8084): GC_CONCURRENT freed 924K, 50% free 3415K/6727K, external 2059K/2108K, paused 5ms+3ms
08-06 08:15:11.515: D/AndroidRuntime(8084): Shutting down VM
08-06 08:15:11.515: W/dalvikvm(8084): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.locationinfofinder/com.project.locationinfofinder.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at com.project.locationinfofinder.MarkerDataSource.CursorToMarker(MarkerDataSource.java:54)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at com.project.locationinfofinder.MarkerDataSource.getMyMarkers(MarkerDataSource.java:41)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at com.project.locationinfofinder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:110)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-06 08:15:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(8084):     ... 11 more
08-06 08:15:17.156: D/dalvikvm(8084): GC_CONCURRENT freed 748K, 47% free 3580K/6727K, external 1771K/2108K, paused 3ms+10ms
08-06 08:15:17.164: D/Cursor(8084): Database path: /data/data/com.project.locationinfofinder/databases/marker_location
08-06 08:15:17.164: D/Cursor(8084): Table name   : location
08-06 08:15:17.164: D/Cursor(8084): SQL          : SQLiteQuery: SELECT loc_title, loc_snippet, loc_position FROM location
08-06 08:15:17.164: I/dalvikvm(8084): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
08-06 08:15:17.164: I/dalvikvm(8084): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@405aa588 on location that has not been deactivated or closed
08-06 08:15:17.164: I/dalvikvm(8084):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:620)
08-06 08:15:17.164: I/dalvikvm(8084):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-06 08:15:48.601: I/Process(8084): Sending signal. PID: 8084 SIG: 9
```

these are code with logcat. i can't find proper solution. in some problem was same and in some answer map would not load.how can i eliminate this problem.please .thanx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your code with this

```
public List<MarkerObj> getMyMarkers()
{
    List<MarkerObj> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerObj>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(MarkerDb.TABLE_NAME, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) 
    {
        MarkerObj m = CursorToMarker(cursor);
        markers.add(m);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return markers;
}
```

Comment: yes this worked and i like to ask another one that i want to add places in sqlite database when search it marker appears in map. thanx.

Comment: your code worked but when i added marker, close app than and start app than the problem is same the app start and freeze no map and crash after certain time

Comment: debug your code first .. may be you have another problem @mirroroftruth

Comment: i want to add palaces in sqlite and a search button on map like google map app so that when search places it shows the marker of the places.

Comment: then put all your location on starting of your activity.

Comment: the error is still there and i cant find any problem here. it happen even adding marker if i kill the task or stop it and start it than problem arises till i uninstall it and install it again and if i add marker in activity more than one than it app freeze and crash after sometime